# Is there a equivalent of PlayerEntity.getPosition in the 1.16 version of Forge

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to create a pair of boots that allows the user to walk over lava. My code:

```
if (world.getFluidState(player.getPosition().down()).getFluid() == Fluids.LAVA) { // Check if lava is below the player
    Vector3d motion = player.getMotion();
    if (motion.y < 0)
        motion = motion.mul(1, 0, 1); // Stop the player from falling into the lava
    player.setMotion(motion);
}
```

However, the function `.getPosition` seems to be deprecated. Is there an equivalent version of this function in the 1.16 version of Forge? the `.getPositionVec` returns a vector, but I'm not sure how to use that in my function.

Answer (score 0):

If your `player` implements `ICommandSender` then you should be able to use the following

```
ChunkCoordinates coords = player.getPlayerCoordinates();
```

afterwards you have access to `coords.posX`/`coords.posY`/`coords.posZ`.

For more info check out [this source](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=net.minecraft.command.ICommandSender&method=getPlayerCoordinates)

Comment: How would get the BlockPos from that to pass into the .getFluidState function?